# Quickest/Shortest way to check array existence and condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I feel this is a really simple question but as a beginner I cannot find the answer.

Ultimately I want to check an element exists in an array (*e.g.* `userProfile.friendRequests`).

I end up using `includes` as a simple check *i.e.*

```
checkRequest(friendReqUid) {
  return userProfile.friendRequests.includes(friendReqUid)
}
```

However sometimes that array might not even exist and the only way that I can see to check the condition is to add a check for the entire array beforehand *i.e.*

```
 checkRequest(friendReq) {
   return userProfile.friendRequest && userProfile.friendRequest.includes(friendReq)
 }
```

If I do this within the template (to show a button, etc.) this ends up being really long winded way to do this.

Is there a quicker function/way to check that an array exists and if an element is present or not, instead of adding another check for the presence of the actual array?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe `(userProfile.friendRequest || []).includes(friendReq)`

Comment: in template, you only need to add `?` to guard against nullable, i.e. Safe Navigation Operator

Comment: As for "quickest" the cost of that check is absolutely insignificant so it simply does not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortest way to do it that I know of is to default to an empty array if the property is falsy:

```
(userProfile.friendRequests || []).includes(friendReqUid)
```

But I usually check if the object exists before accessing the array, so it is more robust:

```
(userProfile && userProfile.friendRequests || []).includes(friendReqUid)
```

**EDIT**: If you want to do the same for `push()`, you can do this:

```
userProfile && (userProfile.friendRequests = userProfile.friendRequests || []).push(friendReqUid)
```

This will initialize the array to `[]` if it is falsy.

However, you might consider splitting this on separate lines so it is more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the answers on this. I now use this for includes, but it won't work on a push command. I sometimes have to do `if (!userProfile.friendRequests) { userProfile.friendRequsts = [ ]} userProfile.friendRequests.push(uid)` - Is there another operator that would work for this?

Comment: For a push, if your array does not exist, you can either not push, or create the array and push, if you want to skip the push, `arr && arr.push(item)` is sufficient. If you want to create the array firt, you have to do it in two steps: `arr = arr || []; arr.push(item)` or `(arr = arr || []).push(item)`, but this is not so readable...